# Apache2 ProxPassReverse with tomcat redirection and context

Tags: redirect, reverse-proxy, tomcat8, apache2.4

I'm not able to configure correctly my apache2 reverse proxy for a context tomcat application.

I'm using the url www.projet-okinawa.ch in browser to externally access the application.

My tcp port 80 is routed to 8080 by iptables.

```
(sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080)
```

I defined a virtual host to catch the url www.projet-okinawa.ch from the port 8080 and redirect the request to the ssl port.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName www.projet-okinawa.ch
        ServerAlias projet-okinawa.ch
        Redirect permanent / https://www.projet-okinawa.ch:8443/
</VirtualHost>

I defined a second virtual host to catch the same url from the port 8443 that enable ssl and manage the reverse proxy.
<VirtualHost *:8443>
        ServerName www.projet-okinawa.ch
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / http://web.projet-okinawa.org:8081/okinawa
        ProxyPassReverse / http://web.projet-okinawa.org:8081/okinawa
        <Location />
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Location>
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/os-vps276.projet-okinawa.org/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/os-vps276.projet-okinawa.org/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/os-vps276.projet-okinawa.org/chain.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

You may note the web application context set to /okinawa.

My tomcat configuration is listening 8080, 8081 and 8443 tcp port.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           proxyName="www.projet-okinawa.ch" proxyPort="8443" scheme="https" />
<Connector port="8443"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           keystoreFile={keystore} keystorePass={password} />
```

The web application execute on Catalina localhost engine under the context /okinawa. The context was not defined by using a context descriptor but by auto deployment. The application executes correctly and it is accessible internally by using the port 8080 (by example: http://web.projet-okinawa.org/okinawa/participatewithus.html).

When accesing it through the proxy by using www.projet-okinawa.ch, I got an HTTP Status 404 - /okinawaokinawa/ exception.

I tested many different way to configure the reverse proxy but without success. I don't understand why the returning url is not backed to www.projet-okinawa.ch without the context that seem duplicated.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error by reading carefully http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html.

"If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument should also end with a trailing /, and vice versa. Otherwise, the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results."

```
ProxyPass / http://web.projet-okinawa.org:8081/okinawa/
ProxyPassReverse / http://web.projet-okinawa.org:8081/okinawa/
```

solved my problem.